# Makefile loop results from ls command

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a list of text files, which when executing the following command:

```
ls *.txt
```

Will result in something like:

```
foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt
```

Now if I want to have the output be something like:

```
File: foo.txt
File: bar.txt
File: baz.txt
```

How would I achieve that in a Makefile?

I've been trying:

```
txtfiles = $$(ls *.txt)

list: $(txtfiles)

$(txtfiles):
    echo "File:" $@
```

But when running this with `make list`, it results with:

```
File: $
File: $
```

I was thinking of trying to achieve this using placeholders `%` but wasn't sure how to do that.

> Note: instead of `$$(ls *.txt)` I'm guessing I could use `$(wildcard *.txt)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: instead of `$$(ls *.txt)` I'm guessing I could use `$(wildcard *.txt)`?

You have to.

Also add `.PHONY: $(txtfiles)` before `$(txtfiles):` rule to make an [explicit request](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Comment: Although I found a solution (as per my answer above), I'm going to mark this as the answer (as it's cleaner than my version)

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figured this out:

```
my_list = $(addsuffix .dep, $(wildcard *.txt))
print_list: $(my_list)
%.dep: %
    @echo "Text File:" $<
```

Run it with `make print_list` to get back the expected result.

Comment: Such approach should be avoided if you want to maintain a readable code.